# Android & GRPC "import io.grpc.examples.helloworld.GreeterGrpc" Error

Tags: android, gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I am trying to develop GRPC on Android Mobile App. I found HelloWorld sample project from https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/v1.34.1/examples/android/helloworld

When I build the project, I got the following error:

import io.grpc.examples.helloworld.GreeterGrpc;
^
symbol:   class GreeterGrpc
location: package io.grpc.examples.helloworld

I am trying to build the app with that gradle:

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.grpc.helloworldexample"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug { minifyEnabled false }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'GoogleAppIndexingWarning', 'HardcodedText', 'InvalidPackage'
        textReport true
        textOutput "stdout"
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.2.0"
    }
    plugins {
        lite {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                remove java
            }
            task.plugins {
                lite { }
            }
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'

      implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.34.1'
       implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.34.1'
       implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.34.1'
       compileOnly 'org.apache.tomcat:annotations-api:6.0.53' // necessary for Java 9+

}
```

The proto file like that:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "io.grpc.examples.helloworld";
option java_outer_classname = "HelloWorldProto";
option objc_class_prefix = "HLW";

package helloworld;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

Is there any problem in the code or gradle file? Could you help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you are missing the generated GreeterGrpc service code. You need to feed `protoc` compiler the gRPC-Java codegen plugin in order to get the generated gRPC code.

```
protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.12.0" }
    plugins {
        grpc { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.34.1" }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java { option 'lite' }
            }
            task.plugins {
                grpc { // Options added to --grpc_out
                    option 'lite' }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note I've changed to use `protoc` v3.12.0 in this case. If you are using `protoc` older than v3.8.0, it would be

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.2.0"
    }
    plugins {
        lite {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0"
        }
        grpc {
            // some old grpc version, newer ones may not work, suggest upgrading
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.22.3"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                remove java
            }
            task.plugins {
                lite { }
                grpc { // Options added to --grpc_out
                    option 'lite' }
            }
        }
    }
}
```